# List of Dictionaries to DataFrame

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a data like this and I want the data to be written in a dataframe so that I can convert it directly into a csv file.

```
Data = 
[ {'event': 'User Clicked', 'properties': {'user_id': '123', 'page_visited': 'contact_us', etc},
{'event': 'User Clicked', 'properties': {'user_id': '456', 'page_visited': 'homepage', etc} , ...... 
{'event': 'User Clicked', 'properties': {'user_id': '789', 'page_visited': 'restaurant', etc}} ]
```

This is How I am able to access its values:

```
for item in list_of_dict_responses:
            print item['event']
            for key, value in item.items():
                if type(value) is dict:
                    for k, v in value.items():
                        print k,v
```

I want it in a dataframe where event is a column with value of User Clicked and properties is a another column with sub column of `user_id, page_visited, contact_us` and then respective values of sub column.

Answer (score 2):

flatten the nested dictionaries & then just use the data frame constructor to create a data frame.

```
data = [ 
  {'event': 'User Clicked', 'properties': {'user_id': '123', 'page_visited': 'contact_us'}},
  {'event': 'User Clicked', 'properties': {'user_id': '456', 'page_visited': 'homepage'}},
  {'event': 'User Clicked', 'properties': {'user_id': '789', 'page_visited': 'restaurant'}} 
]
```

The flattened dictionary may be constructed in several ways. Here's 1 method using a generator that is generic & will work with arbitrary-depth nested dictionaries (or at least until it hits the max recursion depth)

```
def flatten(kv, prefix=[]):
    for k, v in kv.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from flatten(v, prefix+[str(k)])
        else:
            if prefix:
                yield '_'.join(prefix+[str(k)]), v
            else:
                yield str(k), v
```

Then using list comprehension to flatten all the records in `data`, construct the data frame

```
pd.DataFrame({k:v for k, v in flatten(kv)} for kv in data)
#Out
          event properties_page_visited properties_user_id
0  User Clicked              contact_us                123
1  User Clicked                homepage                456
2  User Clicked              restaurant                789
```

Comment: Nice generic solution +1

Comment: @jpp, thanks, this comes up frequently for me when first loading datasets and not knowing the nesting structure, this helper function is a lifesaver.

Comment: Thanks fr the help. But problem is I am using Mixpanel and my program is requesting mixpanel to give me data through the 'request' function, when Data arrives I pre process it and saves it into a structure which I showed u above, Its not allowing me to make new function, can u provide me code snippet which I can add to my 'request' function and returns the format which u have defined.

Comment: @SalmanAhsan, i'm not sure, but once you get the data as a list of dictionaries why don't you use my code snippet to transform to a data frame

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options: either use a `MultiIndex` for columns, or add a prefix for data in `properties`. The former, in my opinion, is not appropriate here, since you don't have a "true" hierarchical columnar structure. The second level, for example, would be empty for `event`.

Implementing the second idea, you can restructure your list of dictionaries before feeding to `pd.DataFrame`. The syntax `{**d1, **d2}` is used to combine two dictionaries.

```
data_transformed = [{**{'event': d['event']},
                     **{f'properties_{k}': v for k, v in d['properties'].items()}} \
                    for d in Data]

res = pd.DataFrame(data_transformed)

print(res)

          event properties_page_visited properties_user_id
0  User Clicked              contact_us                123
1  User Clicked                homepage                456
2  User Clicked              restaurant                789
```

This also aids writing to and reading from CSV files, where a `MultiIndex` can be ambiguous.